# Decimal numbers are not stored as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

When I want to store decimal numbers in mysql decimal field formatted like**(8,4)**, but it's not stored completely. ie **13850** is stored as **13.0000**. 
This is my code in controller (Laravel):

```
$getRate = DB::table('currency_rates')
        ->select('crt_id','buy_rate')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
        $rate = $getRate->buy_rate;
        $c_price = ($unit_price*$rate);
        $expense->c_price = number_format($c_price,4);
        $expense->c_total = number_format($quantity*$c_price,4);
//            dd(number_format($quantity*$c_price,4));
        $expense->rate_id = $getRate->crt_id;
```

Your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

DECIMAL(8,4) means that the number can have up to 8 digits and 4 of them must be after the point, so your range is -9999.9999 to 9999.9999.

You have to allow more digits to store 13850.

UPDATE: Don't use number_format() before storing number to database, use it when displaying only.
Number_format uses comma as a thousands separator, but comma can't be stored in any numeric field in mysql.

number_format(13850, 4) returns string "13,850.0000" and that's why you get 13 stored in database.

Comment: Thank for the reply, and you mean I increase the number of digits like (16,4) ?